# Why does python keep buffering stdout even when flushing and using -u?

Tags: python, stdout, pipe, buffering

```
$ cat script.py
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()

$ cat script.py - | python -u script.py
```

The output is right but it only starts printing once I hit Ctrl-D whereas the following starts printing right away :

```
$ cat script.py - | cat
```

which led me to think that the buffering does not come from cat.

I managed to get it working by doing :

```
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ""):
```

as explained here : [Streaming pipes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187785/streaming-pipes-in-python), but I don't understand why the former solution doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python manpage reveals the answer to your question:

```
   -u     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.  Note that
          there  is  internal  buffering  in  xreadlines(),  readlines()  and file-object iterators ("for line in sys.stdin") which is not influenced by this
          option.  To work around this, you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()" inside a "while 1:" loop.
```

That is: file-object iterators' internal buffering is to blame (and it doesn't go away with -u).

Answer (score 1):

cat does block buffering by default if output is to a pipe. So when you include - (stdin) in the cat command, it waits to get EOF (your ctrl-D closes the stdin stream) or 8K (probably) of data before outputting anything.

If you change the cat command to "cat script.py |" you'll see that it works as you expected.

Also, if you add 8K of comments to the end of script.py, it will immediately print it as well.

Edit:

The above is wrong. :-)

It turns out that file.next() (used by file iterators, ie. for line in file) has a hidden read-ahead buffer that is not used by readline(), which simply reads a character until it sees a newline or EOF.

Comment: I edited my question, explaining why it doesn't seem to come from cat itself.

Comment: Your change makes no difference... it's the first cat that is buffering because the output is going to a pipe. Changing the sink after the pipe will not change anything. You can see this by simply doing "cat script.py -" and seeing that it outputs script.py immediately since it is going to a terminal and not a pipe.

Comment: Maybe my example isn't clear but I think it shows that the first cat does NOT buffers since the content of script.py shows up before EOF is send to the first cat.

Comment: Like I said, add 8K of comments to script.py and you'll see it work.

Comment: I understand that cat may buffer its output, but I showed that in this case, it doesn't (eg `cat script.py - | cat`). Your answer is irrelevant to my problem.